# Erlang releases with Rebar: What am I missing?

Tags: erlang, release, rebar

Thanks to much help here, I'm well on my way toward building my first Erlang release. No real code yet, but I want to understand how it's done. I've consulted and followed several web tutorials as well Martin et. al., but still seem to be missing something.

When I try to start my release I get:

```
lloyd@Reliance:~/Programming/Erlang/learn$ sh rel/learn/bin/learn start
[: 129: Node 'learn@127.0.0.1' not responding to pings.: unexpected operator
```

Under the project directory "learn" I have:

```
apps  rebar  rebar.config  rel
```

In rebar.config, I have:

```
{cover_enabled, true}.
{sub_dirs, ["rel","apps/zzz", "apps/zzz_lib"]}.
```

In ...learn/apps, I have:

```
zzz  zzz_lib
```

zzz and zzz_lib have all the right stuff in them so far as I can tell. From lean, I can clean, compile, and create docs.

In .../rel,I have:

```
files  learn  reltool.config
```

See reltool.config below.

I'm missing magic sauce, but what?

Many thanks,

LRP

```
{sys, [
   {lib_dirs, []},
   {rel, "learn", "1",
    [
     kernel,
     stdlib,
     sasl
    ]},
   {rel, "start_clean", "",
    [
     kernel,
     stdlib
    ]},
   {boot_rel, "learn"},
   {profile, embedded},
   {excl_sys_filters, ["^bin/.*",
                       "^erts.*/bin/(dialyzer|typer)"]},
   {app, sasl, [{incl_cond, include}]}
  ]}.

{target_dir, "learn"}.

{overlay, [
       {mkdir, "log/sasl"},
       {copy, "files/erl", "{{erts_vsn}}/bin/erl"},
       {copy, "files/nodetool", "{{erts_vsn}}/bin/nodetool"},
       {copy, "files/learn", "bin/learn"},
       {copy, "files/app.config", "etc/app.config"},
       {copy, "files/vm.args", "etc/vm.args"}
       ]}.
```

Comment: You don't include your apps ("zzz", "zzz_lib") in the "learn" release.  Also your lib_dirs is empty. Is that intended? If you followed a tutorial, you should show us all the steps that you've gone through. Also, I would suggest you to look at http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_handling.html before diving into the deep magic waters of rebar. It will help you understand how Erlang releases work and what rebar does behind the scenes.

Comment: Also, the release chapter in Learn You Some Erlang is out: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/release-is-the-word -- reading it should give you some hints and ideas about how reltool operates.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like your retool.config file is missing some entries for the application you have written.

The first part should look something like this.

```
{sys, [
   {lib_dirs, ["../apps"]},      <--- point to where your applications are
   {rel, "learn", "1",
    [
     <your application here>     <---- add your application(s) here 
     kernel,
     stdlib,
     sasl
    ]},
   {rel, "start_clean", "",
    [
     kernel,
     stdlib
    ]},
   {boot_rel, "learn"},
   {profile, embedded},
   {excl_sys_filters, ["^bin/.*",
                       "^erts.*/bin/(dialyzer|typer)"]},
   {app, <your application here>, [{incl_cond, include}]},      <-- and here 
   {app, sasl, [{incl_cond, include}]}
  ]}.
```

Here is a sample application from Erlang and OTP in Action that I packaged up using rebar.
https://github.com/tmcgilchrist/simple_cache

The general layout I follow is

```
  simple_cache
          |-> apps  
          |    \-> simple_cache
          |             |-> src
          |             \-> ebin
          |
          |-> rebar.config
          |-> rel
               |-> files 
               |-> reltool.config
               \-> simple_cache
```

Also rather that doing

```
sh rel/learn/bin/learn start
```

use

```
sh rel/learn/bin/learn console
```

and enter

> application:which_applications().

Which should list a bunch of things plus your application.
eg

```
[{mysample_app,[],[]},
 {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.1.10"},
 {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.17.5"},
 {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.14.5"}]
```